# Getting id then selecting that element - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm often finding myself getting various attributes, such as the id of an element or class, then selecting that element and doing something.

What I do now for example is:

```
  var id = $(this).closest(".item").attr('id');
  $('#'+id).hide();
```

Is using '#' and including the id the best way to do this? is there a way to maybe chain these actions together?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also want the id at the end, you can chain them like this:

```
 var id = $(this).closest(".item").hide().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are then going on to manipulate the elements as you do above, a more flexible way would be:

```
var item = $(this).closest(".item");
item.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with that method. You might be able to scrunch it into one line, but why?

```
var id = $(this).closest(".item").hide().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you can't just do

```
$(this).closest(".item").hide();
```

Getting the ID and then performing another jQuery selection is going to be slower than this.

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting the item in order to get the id. All you have to do is `hide()` it there:

```
$(this).closest(".item").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just curious as to whether using $(this).closest(".item") without selecting the .attr("id") would work, then just hiding the found closest element. That would save the last line of code, roll it into one line of code. jQuery commands are chainable, so you should just be able to extend your hide command off the same line of code as the .closest() function will return the desired element.

example:

```
$(this).closest(".item").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if I've understood you correctly, but are you looking for something like this:

$(this).closest(".item").hide();

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/alexkey/UtcKk/